# Why not grow a forest of Groots?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

At the end of Guardians of the Galaxy we see Rocket take a twig of Groot and propagate it as a cutting.  Why stop at one? Why not grow an entire  forest of Groots?

Comment: I'm flagging this question as Groot because I am Groot.

Comment: Sure, but... why?

Answer (score 14):

### Why not have a thousand babies?

Groot is a *person*.  Baby Groot is a *child*.  Unless they were willing and capable of take on the role of parenthood to a thousand children, creating a forest of Groots would be unwise and unethical.